# Difference between hashmap 1.4 and 1.6

Tags: java, hashmap

I have application which runs on both `1.4` and `1.6`. Order of elements is getting printed in `1.6` version is different than `1.4`. I used `LinkedHashMap` which fixed the problem. Now this order is exactly same as of `1.4`. I didn't find `1.4` source code of `HashMap` except downloading entire jdk . Except generic whats been changed in newer versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iteration order of elements in `HashMap` was never guaranteed, so implementations were free to change it. This shortcoming has been remedied by `LinkedHashMap`.

Such a change might be caused by e.g. the [complete revamping of the hashing algorithm in Java 1.4.1](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue054.html)... but then again, we also noticed such a change upon migrating our project to Java6 so there was a change in that version too.

Answer (score 2):

The order of iteration in `HashMap` is *undefined*. That means it can (and does) change all the time. It depends not only on the code, but on the values of the hash codes of objects, which themselves can differ not only from version to version, but even from run to run.

`LinkedHashMap` exists specifically as a `HashMap` alternative with a predictable iteration order.

Comment: I agree that order depends on hashcode of objects and that was the reason it always used to be the same order in older and new version for every run. What I don't understand is order getting changed for every run in any version? I always used to get the same order for every run.

Comment: Or this behavior was seen due to keys' hashcode was calculated by one of String field of object?

Comment: I meant that the order can vary on different runs if your keys use the default `Object.hashCode()`; those values are based ultimately on memory addresses and therefore change between runs.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the implementation of HashMap has changed. HashMap doesn't guarantee any order, so you shouldn't rely on that, because the could change it with new releases without any notice.